# PHP: Scraping website that use timestamps and possibly server side cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies

I run a small website to do with computer games and was looking to pull in some product information from toysrus.ie website, now the problem is that the website looks to be using some cryptic posting format to load pages and it has a timestamp I can't replicate in PHP in the URLs and it looks to be using server side cookies aswell.

Now I've tried using PHP to get the page in question to load with the below but just returns a .

```
$url = 'http://www.toysrus.ie/FilterSearchByManufacturer.action?manuId=1668&t=1453585863738';

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

I've gotten the `$url` above by going to the website and clicking on 'Video Games' top level menu item and then once the page loads, scroll down the left to the drop down box and selecting 'Nintendo' which gives me the url `http://www.toysrus.ie/FilterSearchByManufacturer.action?manuId=1668&t=1453585863738`.

For the `t=1453585863738` part I tried using PHP's `time()` function like below with no luck the session still times out after a couple of seconds. even if it did work and there were more then one page of products I can't go to the next ones due to the `t` variable issue.

```
$url = sprintf('http://www.toysrus.ie/FilterSearchByManufacturer.action?manuId=1668&t=%s', time());

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Now if there are more then one page of results listed then the same issue arises with `t` not being the same as `time()` and the session timing out.

`t` looks to be 13 characters long whereas `time()` only returns 10 characters.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, thanks for that, it's very possible but my question wasn't as to why I can't do this, it was asking for assistance to see if I can accomplish what I'm trying to do, as I said it's a small website I run for a local gaming group, nothing massive or big, I can live without it but if needs be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guess I can make is that this is the UNIX timestamp in microseconds. So in PHP you can use `floor(microtime(true) * 1000);` (instead of the `time()` method) for that.

The `microtime` method gives the time (including the microseconds) in seconds, so you have to multiply that out.

So your code will become the following:

```
$url = sprintf('http://www.toysrus.ie/FilterSearchByManufacturer.action?manuId=1668&t=%s', floor(microtime(true) * 1000);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

That would perfectly explain the difference of 3 characters since 1 microsecond is exactly 1000 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are scraping anyway, you can get the timestamp from one of the pages that don't require it.

After clicking around on toysrus a bit the `Video Games` page has the URL http://www.toysrus.ie/ToysRUs/Video-Games/1_2097_-1_-1.action

If you scrape that page and look for `<h2>Manufacturers</h2>` you can find beneath the `option` for `Nintendo` as

```
<option title="NINTENDO (98)" value="FilterSearchByManufacturer.action?manuId=1668&amp;t=1453589317567">NINTENDO (98)</option>
```

which will give you the time stamp you need to pass to your other requests.